# Save schedules (working hours)

Tags: postgresql

I have an app to make appointments with doctors. Doctors have schedules (working hours).

For example, let's say *doctor A* usually works 10:00 - 14:00 on weekdays. I could save this info in each doctor's table; however, there are holidays, sick days and so on- maybe even short days 11:00 - 13:00. How to represent them in the PostgreSQL database?

My current approach is to create a `schedules` table and store the usual working hours. For *doctor A* on weekdays from 10:00 - 14:00, and for other days create separate tables in which we specify when the doctor cannot work.

Comment: use iCalendar RRules and ExDates . There's a PG extension for parsing them too

Comment: "in each doctors table" ... you don't really have one table per doctor, do you? Having one table for all doctors, with a foreign key to a `doctors` table would be better.

Comment: @DavidAldridge No of course I have one table for `doctors`. My issue is maybe it is wrong approach or if there is better one.

Answer (score -1):

save the unavailable hours as a special type of appointment